# Product Page is failing to load

Tags: magento2.2.4

It loads somewhat,but stalls at some point. Here is the page https://cityprintexpress.com/print-shop/business-cards-3-5x2-1.html

In console I get this error

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token x in JSON at position 131
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
at getData (main.js:58)
at Array.map (<anonymous>)
at HTMLDocument.apply (main.js:74)
at fire (jquery.js:3232)
at Object.add [as done] (jquery.js:3291)
at jQuery.fn.init.jQuery.fn.ready (jquery.js:3542)
at jQuery.fn.init (jquery.js:2967)
at new jQuery.fn.init (jquery-migrate.js:225)
at jQuery (jquery.js:75)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the product name or the caption of the image, the x that you have from the error is coming from the name, potentially because of the double quotes being escaped in the JSON.

This product works as it doesn't have the same pattern for the product name: https://cityprintexpress.com/print-shop/banner-13oz-vinyl.html

Comment: Eric if that helped, please accept his answer and vote up.